# Date formatting in Android

Tags: android, simpledateformat

I have a problem that I want to parse a String to Date in 'November 15, 2013' format but I unable to do that using MMMM D, YYYY in SimpleDateFormat Class. Please suggest any solution regarding to the same.

Code:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM DD, yyyy");
try {
    Date publishedDate = formatter.parse(pictureDirectory.replace(str, ""));
    hashMap.put(publishedDate, getImageFromSdCard(picturePath));
} catch (ParseException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

It always returns 'Fri Nov 15 00:00:00 IST 2013'.

Comment: This only shows how you parse the date. How are you printing it?

Comment: Question is not about printing, but it is not returning the result I want. Please suggest any solution regarding to this.

Comment: Well if it's "returning" something and you say it returns 'Fri Nov 15 00:00:00 IST 2013', there's some way you get that result displayed somewhere but the question doesn't say how.

Comment: Oh I am debugging the code and get Inspect on the particular variable to check what it returns.

Comment: The debugger shows what `Date.toString()` outputs. It's not formatted to anything specific.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the example from Android at [SimpleDateFormat](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

```
String[] formats = new String[] {
   "yyyy-MM-dd",
   "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm",
   "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mmZ",
   "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSZ",
   "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ",
 };
 for (String format : formats) {
   SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(format, Locale.US);
   System.out.format("%30s %s\n", format, sdf.format(new Date(0)));
   sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
   System.out.format("%30s %s\n", format, sdf.format(new Date(0)));
 }
```

Output:

```
                 yyyy-MM-dd 1969-12-31
                 yyyy-MM-dd 1970-01-01
           yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm 1969-12-31 16:00
           yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm 1970-01-01 00:00
          yyyy-MM-dd HH:mmZ 1969-12-31 16:00-0800
          yyyy-MM-dd HH:mmZ 1970-01-01 00:00+0000
   yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSZ 1969-12-31 16:00:00.000-0800
   yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSZ 1970-01-01 00:00:00.000+0000
 yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ 1969-12-31T16:00:00.000-0800
 yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ 1970-01-01T00:00:00.000+0000
```

Comment: Among all outputs I didn't get the same as 'MMMM DD, YYYY' eg: 'November 15, 2013'. Please suggest any solution to this only. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: @SanatPandey the Y need to be small. 'MMMM DD, yyyy'

Answer (score 0):

you could do something like this

```
SimpleDateFormat orignalFormat= new SimpleDateFormat("MMMMMMMMM dd, yyyy"); //November 15, 2013
            Date date = null;
            try {
                    date = origFormat.parse(apkgalaxy.getPosted_on());              
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

and set the day in desired format by below code

```
SimpleDateFormat newFormat_date= new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd"); //any format you want
                if (date!=null) {
                    String desiredDateFormat = newFormat_date.format(date);
                    holder.posted_on_date.setText(desiredDateFormat);
                }else{
                    holder.posted_on_date.setText("N/A");
                }
```

Comment: No it always returns as 'Fri Nov 15 00:00:00 IST 2013'. Thanks for your Commwent.

Comment: @SanatPandey but that's the correct date if you parse "November 15, 2013", isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should be using a mutable object such as Date as a key to a HashMap. Consider converting the date to a String.  This is how I would format a date.

```
DateFormat formatter1 = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMMM DD, yyyy");
System.out.println(formatter1.parse("15/02/2013"));
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment but my problem is different. I want the Format String as 'November 15, 2013' such as 'mmmm dd, yyyy'.

Comment: Change MMMM to MMMMM.

Comment: result remains same after this too.

Comment: Fri Nov 15 00:00:00 IST 2013

Comment: but formatter always returns Date object. we have to take Date while formating.

Answer (score 0):

Since SimpleDateFormat is Depreciated

I would suggest you to use this way

```
android.text.format.DateFormat dateFormat= new android.text.format.DateFormat();
dateFormat.format("MMMM DD, yyyy", new java.util.Date());
```