# Converting DateTime Format to date

Tags: android, datetime

I have an object `2014-01-09T09:33:20+0530`. I want to convert this object to `2014-01-09`.

I saw one answer in StackOverflow.

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(yourObject.ToString(), "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

String s = dt.ToString("dd/M/yyyy");
```

But this is not working in android.

Comment: you can visit my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20882981/date-formating-in-android/20883060#20883060

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [SimpleDateFormat](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) class and you can convert it into any format you want.

```
String dateStr = "2014-01-09T09:33:20+0530"; 
SimpleDateFormat curFormater = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd"); 
Date dateObj = curFormater.parse(dateStr); 

String newDateStr = curFormater.format(dateObj);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static String converDateFormate(String oldpattern,
            String newPattern, String dateString) throws ParseException {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(oldpattern);
        Date testDate = null;
        testDate = sdf.parse(dateString);
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(newPattern);
        String newFormat = formatter.format(testDate);
        System.out.println("" + newFormat);
        return newFormat;
    }
```

CALL this function like this:

```
converDateFormate("dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss", "dd/mm/yyyy", "12/12/2012 12:12:12");
```

i hope its useful to you.

Answer (score 0):

```
 SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        String dateInDatabaseFormat = sdf.format(dateObject);
```